# I want to use Git via macports instead of Apple Git

Tags: git, macos, macports

I'd like to use the latest version Git via macports instead of Apple Git. But when I type `git --version` on terminal app, it displays Apple Git version.

Could you tell me how to use the latest version git on Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have xCode and macports installed and properly working. In order to use macports `git` first you have to install it:

`sudo port install git`

And then add this line to your to `.profile` file in your home directory:

`export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`

Something like this `echo "export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH" >> $HOME/.profile"` should do it.

As a last step you must `source` the `.profile` or `.bash_profile` for these changes to take effect like this: `source $HOME/.profile`.

To summarize, open the terminal on MacOSX and type:

```
$ sudo port install git
$ echo "export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH" >> $HOME/.profile
$ source .profile
$ which git
/opt/local/bin/git
```

Every time you load the shell the MacPorts path should be available. In case this doesn't work, try using `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` to save the environment $PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's now 2022 and my Mac is using zsh. I wanted to use MacPorts to update git to latest version instead of using Apple Git. I do not use Homebrew.

```
% git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

%which git
/usr/bin/git

% port contents git
Port git is not installed.
```

So clearly, my computer is using Apple Git.
I need to update MacPorts and install git

```
% sudo port selfupdate 
// macports updates

% sudo port install git
// macports installs git

% port contents git
// now lots of files get listed
```

However, at this point, my computer is still using Apple Git.

```
% git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

%which git
/usr/bin/git
```

So now I just need to update my ".zshrc" file by adding a new PATH for MacPorts git. MacPorts puts things in "/opt/local/bin", so we need to let our shell know that.
Edit the .zshrc with vim (or vi or pico)

```
% vim ~/.zshrc
```

With the editor open, add these lines (in there somewhere, just find a good spot [make sure there are no other Git related PATH additions])

```
# PATH for MacPorts git install
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Save the file.

At this point, I would suggest just rebooting your console session (you don't need to reboot machine). Alternatively, you could type this line in the console...

```
source .zshrc
```

At this point, if all has gone well, you should now be using the latest Git.

```
% git --version
git version 2.35.3
% which git
/opt/local/bin/git
```

Luck be with you!